# Translating many meshes - HLSL

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

Okay forgive me if this is at all vague, but I've been up all night trying to catch up with some coding.

I have a reasonably large and defined terrain with minimal optimisations in place and I have just started to introduce predefined meshes (.X objects) which come with materials and textures. Previously I was working in a fixed-function-pipeline approach as I have only recently started working with DirectX9. It has become apparent that FFP is old school and deprecated in DirectX10, so I have been moving relevant code to using a HLSL approach.

In my initial approach I had loaded my models into a std::vector container of models and created another std::vector of objects which contain a reference to which model to display. In my render loop, I would iterate this container and check to see if the objects were within the Field-of-view of my camera. If so I would first translate the meshes to their positions, using a SetTransform() call, then DrawSubset().

However it has become clear that SetTransform() is not applicable to the HLSL approach; therefore I'm a little stumped to how I can pre-translate these meshes to their relevant positions, or whether I should be translating them within the vertex shader. The meshes are stored within an ID3DXMESH type and it seems that I can access the Index and Vertex Buffer of these meshes; Am I supposed to take the contents of these buffers, translate the contents then draw them? Or am I really going the wrong way about doing this?

I am familiar with the Vertex Buffer approach, but not sure what the vertex format is within the mesh itself.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm about to tear my eyeballs out.

**Edit**

I'll accept Sergio's answer as it pushed me in the right direction although the solution came when I realised in my debug output a line about committing changes.

**Solution**

After transforming my mesh I needed to call
g_pEffect->CommitChanges();

Comment: I don't have enough DirectX API knowledge to fully answer your question. But yes, you generally do the transformation in the vertex shader. You pass a WorldViewProjection transformation matrix into your shader as a shader constant.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your reply. Yes I have a WorldViewProjection matrix passed into my shader, I am using it for my lighting/shading calculations. However what I am struggling with is that my meshes are all pre-translated with an origin of 0,0,0. I don't really want say 1000 trees all stuck at 0,0,0 which is what I am getting since I moved to HLSL; as I can't do the SetTransform() calls between my DrawSubset() calls. So I can't for the life of me figure out how I'm going to translate them into world space from object space; ideally I'd like to pre-translate them all at initialisation stage.

Comment: Jay, I've had the same problem for the last hour. Thanks for figuring it out! I was following two tutorials but both didn't mention CommitChanges :/

Comment: No problem :) glad my troubles helped you out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone said earlier you should be doing the translation on your vertex shader, if you have a worldViewProjection matrix constant within your shader, then you need to multiply the vertex position by that matrix and return the transformed position on your output before you move onto your pixel shader.

Make sure the world transform you are passing in with your view and projection is not just an identity as this wont transform the verts at all.

This is a sample on how you can achieve this on your vertex shader, which is essentially multiplying the incoming untransformed vertex position by the worldViewProj matrix.

```
VS_OUTPUT vs_main( float4 inPos: POSITION )
{ 
  VS_OUTPUT output;

  output.pos = mul( inPos, g_worldViewProj );

  return output; 
}
```

Comment: Hey you might have hit something there :) I'm using the Identity matrix as my landscape and skybox is pre-translated as it's easy to do during generation. I think you may have just nailed it for me Sergio :)

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I already have code which does this; but you mentioning the identity matrix has triggered alarm bells in my head to why it's not working!! :)

Comment: Still isn't working though, I'm doing exactly that, setting the effect param within my tree draw loop as each tree has a matrix to be transformed by in order to translate into world space; i just end up with 1000 trees at 0,0,0 even though at the top of my render loop my world matrix is being set back to what it should be.